# Count the number of times where the next log entry came after one or more minutes than the last one

Tags: shell-script, grep, logs

I have a log file that records the date, time (hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds), the speed of a vehicle and the free distance between the vehicle and the vehicle in front and back of our vehicle. If the vehicle stops, then it doesn't measure the distances.

My `selfdriving.log` file look looks like this:

```
2021.04.01. 13:14:30:78 78 110 110
2021.04.01. 13:14:30:99 79 111 111
2021.04.01. 13:14:31:50 80 111 119
2021.04.01. 13:14:59:87 87 118 117
2021.04.01. 13:16:59:87 86 116 119
2021.04.01. 13:17:22:32 75 117 115
2021.04.01. 13:18:50:65 75 96 109
2021.04.01. 13:18:55:00 0 0 0
```

What I have to do is to write a script that returns the number of times an log entry was made one or more minutes after the last one (so if my calculations are correct, it should return `2` in this case). I don't understand how `grep` works and how I can put the returned values into variables. So far, I've tried:

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in "cat selfdriving.log"
do
  grep (([01][0-9])|(2[0-3])):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]
done
```

Which I know doesn't evaluate to much.

Comment: I'm not understanding your grep expression. Given `2021.04.01. 13:14:30:78 78 110 110`, what is the first `78`? Is that part of the time?

Comment: Also, in your view, _which_ 3 log entries should count? I only see two: 13:16:59 and 13:18:50

Comment: `78` is the speed of the vehicle in km/h. And yeah, you're right, it's only two entries that should count. Edited it.

Comment: This sounds more like an `awk` script: see if the current line is a minute or more ahead of the previous line - if so, count it.

Comment: Given that it's on 2 digits, would that not be *centiseconds* rather than milliseconds? Are those time in local time or UTC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution to problems where you have to compare times is to convert the datetime into an integer number of seconds. Then, if you remember the timestamp from the previous record, you can do the arithmetic to find differences greater than 60 seconds.

GNU awk has [some time functions built-in](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html)

```bsh
gawk -F'[. :]+' '
    {timestamp = mktime($1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6)}
    NR == 1 {prev = timestamp}
    timestamp - prev >= 60 {print}
    {prev = timestamp}
' selfdriving.log
```

```
2021.04.01. 13:16:59:87 86 116 119
2021.04.01. 13:18:50:65 75 96 109
```

To get the count of records, you can

1. pipe that output into `| wc -l` to get the count, or
2. do the counting in awk and print the result in an END block.